# Why are my AI enemies surrendering all the time?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I recently started to play AoE2 again and tried to play some random maps against AI opponents. I set the difficulty to "Moderate" (3 of 5) and started the game. But every time after exactly 5:01 min of play time, my enemies surrender and I win the game...

I know that I'm not an uber pro at playing AoE2 so I don't think I can play on difficulty 4 or even 5, so I'd like to play on "Moderate", but I can't because my enemies surrender after exactly 5 minutes.

What is going on here?

**Update:**
For all who are interested, this is fixed in the Steam version of AoE2HD. I played on difficulties 2/5 and 3/5 and my enemies did not surrender.

Comment: What version of AOE 2 do you have? Also, do you have 'The Conquerors' expansion?

Comment: How can I figure out which version I have? No, it's Age of Kings only.

Comment: From http://aokhelp.jimomighty.com/: You can find your current version by either loading the game and check the version displayed in a multiplayer pre-match screen, viewing the properties on the 'empires2.exe' and checking the results under "Product Version", or attempting to apply the update and viewing the result.

Comment: In multiplayer it says "CD 2.0".

Comment: It might not be updated to the latest version. [The answer here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/59728/4797) by @Kyralessa has information on updating AOE 2.

Comment: a well known way to get around this is to play regicide.

Comment: @TrewTzu Another one (excluding the patch) is to create a random scenario in the map editor, generate a random map and off you go. You also have some extra control on the allowed units (e.g. disable trebuchet).

Comment: I have experienced the same glitch. At 5:01, all players "surrender" and the game is over.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me.  In fact, it sounds quite similar to what's described here (scroll down a bit to the "AI Update" section):

> [Age of Kings: Downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/games/age2/downloads.htm)
>
> The Age of Empires II AI Update - This update addresses the issue where the computer player resigns after a few minutes of play.

That page has patch 2.0a, which applies to Age of Kings.  You can also find that patch here:

[Age of Empires II Update v2.0a](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5264)

If you have The Conquerors expansion, you'll want to go with patch 1.0c instead:

[Age of Empires II: The Conquerors Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us//download/details.aspx?id=20049)

Comment: I think you mixed up with age of empires 2 and age of empires 2 : the conquerors expansion. The later has latest patch `1.0c` while the first one has the latest patch 2.0a.

Comment: @Shiplu, well, that certainly explains why I had so much trouble finding it.  I'll improve the links on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The AI could have triggers built into that after x amount of time...if they are too far behind in score. It will surrender because the amount of time it would take the ai at difficulty level to catch up to you will take too long.

Comment: Okay I had a look at it and when they surrender at 5:01 I am a little bit ahead by points, but only by about 20 points... That would suck hard, if it is something like "difficulty moderate or less? --> 5 minutes have passed? --> human has more points? --> surrender --> else --> continue

Comment: 20 points is not that much...

Comment: I had somewhat around 380 and they had 360.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why the AI surrenders. Some ways that help you avoid this issue include: do not place computer players starting town too close to the edge of the map. Also, the computer will give up when its bank of resources is depleted. That is the short answer with out all the math. Try to give a starting bank of 200 food and wood. Lastly, if you have done these things and the computer still gives up, check for wolves. sometimes the computer will do some crazy pathing, It may be running all of its starting villagers past wolves.